# Groovy local file extension

Tags: file, groovy

Newbie question. How in MarkUpBuilder load local file with specific extension(sql) ?

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import groovy.xml.*

def sw = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)

def dir = new File("C:\\Users\\John\\git\\changelogs\\version1")


xml.dataBaseChangeLog(){
    dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES).eachFileMatch(~/.*.sql/) { file ->   
----------------------------------------------------------^ <- //It's bad
            changeSet(author:"John", ID:"JIRA", failOnError: "True", runAlways: "false")
            sqlFile(path:file, relativeToChangelogFile: "true", encoding: "utf8")    
            rollback(){       
                sqlFile(path:file, relativeToChangelogFile: "true")
    }}}
    println sw
```

Comment: Please define /It's bad/

Comment: It's mean it doesn't work. After `eachFileRecurse` must be clousre i supposed ? How use `eachFileMatch` to find extension what I looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code there is an obvious error:

there is no `java.io.File.eachFileRecurse()` with just one argument: `groovy.io.FileType`

see javadoc: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/io/FileType.html

the simple solution:

```
dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES){
    if(it.name =~/\.txt/ ){
        println "$it"
    }
}
```